# Can someone help me understand how fork worked in this case?

Tags: c, fork, logical-operators

I have this program that I find somewhat misleading and hard to understand:

```
int i=2;
int j=10;
int p;

while(--i && (p=fork())
{
    if(p<0)
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
j=j+2;
if(p==0)
{
   i=i*3;
   j=j*3;
}
else
{
    i=i*3;
    j=j*2;
}
printf("pid=%d i=%d j=%d\n",getpid(),i,j);
```

This program results the following:

> Parent: PIDHERE, i=0, j=24.
>
> Child: PIDHERE, i=3, j=36.

But why does this exactly happen? If parent has i=0 it means the while was executed twice, but doesn't that mean two childs are created instead of one since the while has a fork() statement?

Also, when does the while exactly stop looping? (the logical expression is confusing with the fork()!).

Comment: It would preferable if you posted compilable code: `while(--i && (p=fork())` is missing a close parenthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `--i` predecrements `i`.  The first time the `while` evaluates its condition, it will see `i` has a value of `1`.   The second time, it will see `i` has a value of `0`.  So, the loop will only spawn one child.

The `while` stops when it sees `i` is `0` (in the parent), or if the `fork` returns `0` (in a child).

Comment: The child process will not execute while as its p equals 0, that I can understand. But even with i decrements beore entering the loop, doesn't the paren'ts while have to check the fork as well by default? Thus executing it and creating another child?

Comment: The `||` operator short-circuits. It evaluates its left-hand-side first. If it is true, then it doesn't matter what the right-hand side evaluates to; the result will always be true. So, it doesn't execute further than it needs.  This also happens with `&&`, which stops on the first false.

Comment: the operator is `&&` not `||`

Comment: Oops, so it is.  As I added, the `&&` also short circuits.  When the left hand side is false, it doesn't evaluate the right hand side.

Comment: I think I got it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the predecrement, the while loop is essentially equivalent to:

```
i=1;
p=fork();
if(p<0)
    return 0;
else if(p)
    i=0;
```

`fork()` gets only called once.